# Memory complexity of Boyer–Moore majority vote algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, boyer-moore

Per mine understanding , To find the majority element Boyer–Moore majority vote algorithm   is O(1) i.e. it constant and not proportional to size of input.
Then why thi [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_majority_vote_algorithm) mentions  logarithmic space {\displaystyle O(\log n)} O(\log n)

**Here is the program for reference**

```
public class MajorityElement {
    /* Function to print Majority Element */
    void printMajority(int a[], int size) {
        /* Find the candidate for Majority */
        int cand = findCandidate(a, size);

        /* Print the candidate if it is Majority */
        if (isMajority(a, size, cand))
            System.out.println(" " + cand + " ");
        else
            System.out.println("No Majority Element");
    }

    /* Function to find the candidate for Majority */
    int findCandidate(int a[], int size) {
        int maj_index = 0, count = 1;
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (a[maj_index] == a[i])
                count++;
            else
                count--;
            if (count == 0) {
                maj_index = i;
                count = 1;
            }
        }
        return a[maj_index];
    }

    /*
     * Function to check if the candidate occurs more than n/2 times
     */
    boolean isMajority(int a[], int size, int cand) {
        int i, count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (a[i] == cand)
                count++;
        }
        if (count > size / 2)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why Wikipedia cannot always be relied upon, at least not without some critical thinking on the part of the reader. (Which should not be considered a reason to not use Wikipedia; it's an immensely valuable resource thanks to a vast and committed team of volunteer contributors.)

There are two common models used to measure space and time complexity: the uniform cost model and the logarithmic cost model. The uniform cost model assumes that the storage cost of a single value is `Θ(1)` (regardless of the magnitude of that value) and that the time complexity of a single simple arithmetic computation is also `Θ(1)`. If the values are very large, then these simplifications are not correct, so one might want to use the logarithmic model. In the logarithmic model, we measure the size of the problem not by the count of values, but rather by the total size in bits of the values. [(A different Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Cost_models) provides a discussion of these models. Also see the references.)

This has little impact on simple arithmetic. The cost of adding two `N`-bit numbers is `Θ(N)` and the cost of adding a vector of numbers whose total size is `N` bits is `Θ(N)`, just as it would be with the simplifying assumption that the size of the problem is measured in values and the cost of adding two values is `Θ(1)`. But if multiplication and division are involved, the complexity computations get much more complicated, and it is really not worth going down that road unless the numbers are really very very big, as in, for example, various encryption algorithms which include operations on values whose size is thousands of bits.

While there are algorithms which involve arithmetic on numbers sufficiently large that it needs to be taken into account for an accurate analysis, there really are no practical algorithms which involve so many inputs that the size of the address of a value (in the [random access machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine)) needs to be taken into account. There are not 2<sup>256</sup> subatomic particles in the entire universe, so it is completely reasonable to assume that a limited-bit-width register is sufficient for any addressing purpose, which includes counting the number of participating objects.

Consequently, categorizing an algorithm which needs to maintain a count of inputs as `Θ(log N)` (or `O(log N)`) just because the counter might have an arbitrary number of bits in some alternative universe is, at best, pedantry, and (in my opinion) contributes nothing to the understanding of the complexity of given algorithms.

Nonetheless, pedants have as much right as anyone to contribute to Wikipedia; indeed, it might be theorized that the Wikipedia culture invites pedantry. That still needs to be balanced against the Wikipedia insistence that authors not include "original research", which would include (again, in my opinion) reinterpreting the storage complexity of an algorithm in a way which contradicts commonly published results. (And that might explain the "citation-needed" marker in the Wikipedia article in question.)

Comment: "*2^128 subatomic particles*" I think you mean atoms, otherwise this statement is very problematic.

Comment: @user1803551: You're right, I misremembered the base of the number. Changed the exponent to a safer value.

Comment: Well, I won't get into irrelevant physics arguments, but the number of subatomic particles can be almost infinite considering conservation rules. You also need to account for all the unbounded ones and stuff. I found [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1631/total-number-of-subatomic-particles-in-the-universe-are-they-finite-assuming), but I see it as an incomplete answer. Anyway, the point in your post is well taken regardless.

Comment: @user1803551: Yes, it was exactly the Penrose estimate I misremembered as 2^80. Perhaps Penrose didn't say "subatomic particles"; I don't have the book at my fingertips. But only observable particles could possibly matter.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the variable `count` needs `O(log(n))` bits to store the number of occurences of the candidate. Of course in your daily tests it is unlikely that you will try with arrays of more than 2^32 (or something similar) cells.

Comment: you mean to say that for storing count say 2^31-1 it needs 31 bits right ?